# Loading Stores in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am new to React-Redux, I have a app having all stores preloaded on the `index.js` file which is the entry point that renders the app . I have the following code in the page (a part of it).

```
   if(Auth.isUserAuthenticated()){
  store.dispatch(getProductCategories());
  store.dispatch(getProducts());
  store.dispatch(getAuctions());
  store.dispatch(getAppSettings());
  store.dispatch(getWalletTransactionHistory());
  store.dispatch(getAllUsers());
  store.dispatch(getParticipatedAuctions());
  store.dispatch(getParticipatedAuctionsList());        
  store.dispatch(getWalletBalance())
  }
  store.dispatch(getHomePageAuctions());
  store.dispatch(getAllPageAuctions());
  store.dispatch(getPriceCards());


render(
  <AppContainer>
    <App store={store} history={history} />
  </AppContainer>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

The action in the above are dispatched on every route change, But i Wanted it to dispatch only once on the page load . I even tried to put it on `App component` in `ComponentDidMount()` and also tried in putting it in `constructor()` of that component but no luck didn't work as expected and also searched google but no luck with exact match or similar to it

Comment: have you try componentWillMount() of react may be it can help you.

Comment: @RahulDudharejiya didn't help

Comment: then there is problem on loading your component may be possible that your component loads every time so it call every time if you put it on ComponentDidMount() or constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest moving your store.dispatch calls inside App.js' componentDidMount. Since App.js will only mount once, they'll only fire once.

Comment: I found the problem it was with dev server, It reloads on every page change